# Convert typenameHandling json to regular json

Tags: c#, json.net

Is it possible to convert json produced by JSON.NET with type name handling set on into regular json?

My application cannot assume anything about the types it is receiving as it will be 1 of many 1000s of classes. I just need to remove the type information from the json.

For example I receive this json string in my application:

```
{
  "$type": "MyAssembly.MyType, MyAssembly",
  "$id": 1,
  "MyValue": 5
}
```

Can I convert it into this json:

```
{
  "MyValue": 5
}
```

I've tried loading the original json into JObject and then removing all members starting with `$` but then found this fails when working with arrays, as they can look like this:

```
{
  "MyArray": {
    "$type": "System.Collections.List, System",
    "$values": [
      {
        "$type": "MyAssembly.MyType, MyAssembly",
        "MyValue": 5
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Is there anything built into JSON.NET that allows such a conversion to take place?

---

Here is an example to show what I mean

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        JsonSerializerSettings withNamehandling = new JsonSerializerSettings()
        {
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All,
            ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize,
            PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.All,
            Formatting = Formatting.Indented
        };

        var obj = new MyObj();

        //This is the json which my application will be receiving. My application does not know about MyObj or MyType.
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, withNamehandling);
        Console.WriteLine(json);

        //Deserialize the object without namehandling enabled
        var deserializeObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
        //Serialize again without namehandling enabled
        var json2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(deserializeObject, Formatting.Indented);
        //Metadata removed from root node but not children.
        Console.WriteLine(json2);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

class MyObj
{
    public List<MyType> Types { get; set; } = new List<MyType>()
    {
        new MyType()
        {
            Value = 5
        }
    };
}

class MyType
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do about `PreserveReferencesHandling` tokens like `"$id"` and `"$ref"`?  The first, `"$id"`, is easy enough to remove, but the second is problematic since the `"$ref"` is simply a pointer to elsewhere in the JSON hierarchy.  In the original version of your question there was no requirement to remove `PreserveReferencesHandling` tokens, but you seem to have added that in your update, making it much more complex.

Answer (score 0):

If I use http://json2csharp.com/, below structure I get

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string __invalid_name__$type { get; set; }
    public int __invalid_name__$id { get; set; }
    public int MyValue { get; set; }
}
```

With that what if you create your model as

```
public class MyType
{
    public int MyValue { get; set; }
}
```

And then deserialize it to that type `MyType`

You can as well use `JsonProperty` annotation and make the specific property not required like

```
public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Default)]
    public string __invalid_name__$type { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Default)]
    public int __invalid_name__$id { get; set; }
    public int MyValue { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I need to remove the type information on *any* json.net serialized json before it is pushed out to external applications. I will not know what actual types the json contains so this is not an option. I just need to remove the json.net meta information.

Comment: @NickWilliams, see edit in answer if it helps. Also post your code as how you are deserializing it

Comment: I don't think that helps. My application has no knowledge of `MyType` so I cannot create a class for it. I just need to remove the metadata. Added example program in case it helps

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can deserialize the data and then reserialize it. By default JSON .NET will not include the type names, so that must be set by the serialization side with a purpose, to use the same assembly to serialize/deserialize the data, so be careful when manipulating that data without the real source assembly.

Anyway, to deserialize the data first create a model which fits with the real data:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public List<MyObject> MyArray { get; set; }
}

public class MyObject
{
    public MyType MyValue { get; set; }
}

//I assume this because there's not info about "MyType"
public class MyType : String { }
```

Now you create a `JsonSerializerSettings` and set the `TypeNameHandling` to `None`:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.None };
```

And deserialize the  data to your struct:

```
var deser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(seria, settings);
```

Now you have the data reconstructed and you can reserialize it with no type handling and it will remove all the namespaces and class types:

```
var cleanJson =  JsonConvert.SerializeObject(deser, settings);
```

EDIT:

IF you don't need to reconstruct the structure just use the settings as posted and de/serialize to JObject:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.None };
var deser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(SourceData, settings);
var clean = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(deser, settings);
```

Comment: See update. My application cannot assume anything about the types it is receiving it will be 1 of many 1000s of classes. I just need to remove the type information from the json.

Comment: @NickWilliams See my update. And if you have requirements so strict better explain them on the question.

Comment: I thought I had made it clear, but obviously I hadn't. Anyway your edit gives the same result as my sample, which leaves all of the type information on the array. So the array is still split into `$type` and `$array`